# List of dictionaries of lists into organised pandas df

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dictionary:

```
[
  { 
    'dates': ['2019-12-01'], 
    'periods': ['1', '1', '1', '1']
  }, 
  {
    'dates': ['2019-12-02', '2019-12-03', '2019-12-04', '2019-12-05'], 
    'hh_periods': ['1', '1', '1', '20']
  }
]
```

Ideally, I would like to build a `pd.Dataframe()` with `colums=["p1", "p2", "p3", "p4"]`

That would look like this:

```
           p1 p2 p3 p4
dates                                                 
2019-12-01  1  1  1  1
2019-12-02  1  1  1  20
2019-12-03  1  1  1  20
2019-12-04  1  1  1  20
2019-12-05  1  1  1  20
```

For my use case I need something fast, I have tried:

```
p = pd.DataFrame(data).explode('dates')
p.set_index('dates', inplace=True)
```

Which is close but ends up with:

```
               hh_periods
dates                    
2019-12-01   [1, 1, 1, 1]
2019-12-01   [1, 1, 1, 1]
2019-12-02  [1, 1, 1, 20]
2019-12-03  [1, 1, 1, 20]
```

Which is not ideal. 
*** UPDATE ***

So I have used anky_91 answer of:

```
cols = ["dates", "p1", "p2", "p3", "p4"]
p = pd.DataFrame(self.build()).explode('dates')
var = p[['dates']].join(pd.DataFrame(p.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1].tolist()))
var.columns = cols
```

Now this returns which visually looks correct:

```
dates          p1   p2  p3   p4
0  2019-12-07  1    0    0    0
0  2019-12-14  1    0    0    0
0  2019-12-07  1    0    0    0
0  2019-12-14  1    0    0    0
1  2019-12-01  1    0    0    0
```

But when I test with:

```
[
 {
  'dates': ['2019-12-07', '2019-12-14'], 
  'periods': ['333333', '0', '0', '0']
 }, 
 {
  'dates': ['2019-12-01', '2019-12-08', '2019-12-15'], 
  'periods': ['1', '1', '333', '1']
 }
]
```

I get a df like this:

```
        dates            p1 p2 p3 p4
0  2019-12-07  333333    0    0    0
0  2019-12-14  333333    0    0    0
0  2019-12-07  333333    0    0    0
0  2019-12-14  333333    0    0    0
1  2019-12-01  333333    0    0    0
1  2019-12-08  333333    0    0    0
1  2019-12-15  333333    0    0    0
1  2019-12-01  333333    0    0    0
```

So only p1 is getting picked up... :/

```
p = pd.DataFrame(self.build()).explode('dates')
print(p)
```

Produces the old form as expected :

```
      dates         hh_periods
0  2019-12-07  [333333, 0, 0, 0]
0  2019-12-14  [333333, 0, 0, 0]
1  2019-12-01     [1, 1, 333, 1]
1  2019-12-08     [1, 1, 333, 1]

    ( ... )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
p = pd.DataFrame(data).explode('dates')
p = p[['dates']].join(pd.DataFrame(p.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:,-1].tolist())
                 .rename(columns=lambda x: f"p{x+1}"))
```

---

```
        dates p1 p2 p3  p4
0  2019-12-01  1  1  1   1
1  2019-12-02  1  1  1  20
1  2019-12-03  1  1  1  20
1  2019-12-04  1  1  1  20
1  2019-12-05  1  1  1  20
```

EDIT per new list of dicts:

```
p = pd.DataFrame(data).explode('dates').reset_index(drop=True)
var = p[['dates']].join(pd.DataFrame(p.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:,-1].tolist()))
#var.columns = your_list_of_columns
print(var)
```

---

```
        dates       0  1    2  3
0  2019-12-07  333333  0    0  0
1  2019-12-14  333333  0    0  0
2  2019-12-01       1  1  333  1
3  2019-12-08       1  1  333  1
4  2019-12-15       1  1  333  1
```

Comment: Thank you, and if I wanted to name the cols from a fixed list, how would I do that?

Comment: @Alex  save in a variable before joining `var = pd.DataFrame(p.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:,-1].tolist())` , then name the columns `var.columns = fixed_list` , then join `p[['dates']].join(var)` ?

Comment: I seem to get: 
`ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['dates'], dtype='object')`

Comment: @Alex i see that means your fixed list has `dates` too. in that case save `var = p[['dates']].join(pd.DataFrame(p.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:,-1].tolist())` , `var.columns = fixed_list` then print `var`

Comment: Okay visually looks correct, but testing doesnt look good just yet - let me update my question :)

Comment: @Alex can you check the EDIT? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can fix your p with

```
p = p.reset_index().join(pd.DataFrame(p.hh_periods.tolist()))
```

Comment: OKay cool, but how would I then unravel the list values into their own cols?